# How to change the flip animation in a template Utility Application in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

When creating a Utility application via the template in iOS, having looked through the generated code, is there any way to change the animation from being a Flip animation to a RollUp animation for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the storyboard, choose Segue connected 2 view controllers and change its transition attribute from "Flip Horizontal" to "Cover Vertical"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by RollUp, but you can change it to any of the available transition types in the Presentation Transition Styles enum:

```
typedef enum {
   UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical = 0,
   UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal,
   UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve,
   UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl,
} UIModalTransitionStyle;
```

This is documented in the UIViewController Class Reference.